# rust-analyzer: Failed to write request: Broken pipe (os error 32)

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

Got this error with `rust-analyzer` VS Code, although `cargo build` builds the project without errors or warnings.

`rustc` version: 1.54.0

I would like to stay on the "stable" `rustc` version and **not** shift to "nightly".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update `rustc`  to fix this and ensure that Visual Studio Code uses the correct Rust compiler.

1. Run `rustup update` to update `rustc`
2. Check version used by `rust-analyzer`: Ensure that `ctrl+p -> Rust Analyzer: Show RA Version` shows `rust-analyzer version: 183ef048f 2021-11-22 stable`, or later.
3. Run `cargo clean` to clear obsoleted compiler output
4. Close **all** VS Code windows and open them again.

This should fix the issue. If not, have a look [here](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/10766).